Does polars load the entire parquet into the memory if we want to retrive certain column?
I am new to the data science. I am working on the Polars to read the parquet files. Total size of all these parquet files is 240 GB. I have an EC2 machine with 64 GB and 8 vCP.
I was under the assumption that as Parquet is a columnar file format so whenever I retrieve columns from the Parquet files then it doesn't need to load the entire file into the memory and only loads the required columns. (As a noob I am not sure how it works)
But today when I tried to load 3 columns with the total size of 600 MB (Total column size) then Memory usage went through the roof. It consumed the entire 64 GB of RAM.
I am not able to find any documentation about the lifecycle of loading parquet files into the polars and how it reads the column.
Can someone explain me how this works or point me to good documentation
Here is the code
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# Directory containing the Parquet files
directory = '/home/ubuntu/parquet_files/'

# Load data using Polars
df = pl.scan_parquet(directory)
grouped_df = df.select([
    pl.col("L_SHIPDATE").alias("L_SHIPDATE"),
    pl.col("L_LINESTATUS").alias("L_LINESTATUS"),
    pl.col("L_RETURNFLAG").alias("L_RETURNFLAG")
]).collect(streaming=True)


Are you using scan_parquet or read_parquet? That makes probably all the difference.

It's hard to help without seeing the actual code you're using.

@TeemuRisikko I am using scan_parquet

@AKX i will share it here in few mins

@BhaskarDabhi Any moment now?

@AKX Sorry updated now. The "mins" took me too long :D

scan_parquet() has the low_memory=True option – you could try that. Also, try not passing a list to LazyFrame.select() – the usage hints seem to say to not do that.
